# Create a login in stored procedure with null password using create login query?

Tags: sql-server-2012, sp-executesql, single-quotes

I am not able to correct my query, I want to create login by passing parameter to the create login query with null password?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_login
    (@DLName VARCHAR(50),
     @DBName VARCHAR(50))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(1000)

    SET @statement = 'Create Login ' + @DLName + ' With Password = ' + '''''' + ',' + ' Default_Database = ' + @DBName + ',' + ' Check_Policy = ' + ' Off'

    EXEC sp_executesql @statement, N'@DLName, @DBName', @DLName, @DBName
END
```

Comment: There is syntax error, check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
EXEC sp_executesql @statement, N'@DLName, @DBName', @DLName, @DBName
```

By

```
EXEC sp_executesql @statement
```

Because the statement

```
SET @statement = 'Create Login ' + @DLName + ' With Password = ' + '''''' + ',' + ' Default_Database = ' + @DBName + ',' + ' Check_Policy = ' + ' Off'
```

becomes Plain SQL Query, by concatenating with the parameters passed in Stored Procedure `usp_login`  -  which further doesn't requires any parameter